# Is it possible to Run Python selection in the current terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In `VSCode` we have the command `Python: Run Selection in Python terminal`.

Is it possible to run it in the `current` terminal instead of opening a new terminal?

I need to run some scripts in the current terminal before running the Python line that is the reason I'm asking.

Comment: It seems that when the "Python: Run Selection in Python terminal" command is executed, it is displayed in a default terminal. Have you ever tried to run a line of code that has no effect on the code,(It opens this default terminal.), then "run some scripts" in this terminal, and then click "Python: Run Selection in Python terminal"?

Comment: @Franco Piccolo I know it's been a while, but please, let us know if the answer below is what you needed. If so, please accept it to "close the question". Hope it has helped!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, it is possible. But you will need a shell command for that. I don't think that pressing the `Run Selection in Python terminal` shortcut will work.

Consider you have, for example, two script in the same directory named `test1.py` and `test2.py` with the respective contents:

```
# test1.py 
print("This is the 1st script")
```

and

```
# test2.py 
print("This is the 2nd script")
```

To run them you have the following alternatives (run these commands on the current `zsh` terminal inside the correct directory):

**1** Run scripts sequentially given that one depends on the **success** of the previous ones:

```
% python test1.py && python test2.py
```

Result:

```
This is the 1st script
This is the 2nd script
```

**2** Run scripts sequentially given that one depends on the **failure** of the previous ones:

```
% python test1.py || python test2.py
```

Result when `test1.py` has a bug:

```
File "/Users/Documents/test/test1.py", line 2

^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
This is the 2nd script
```

**3** Run scripts at the same time as background processes:

```
% python test1.py & python test2.py &
```

Result:

```
[1] 29290
[2] 29291
test % This is the 2nd script
This is the 1st script

[2]  + done       python test2.py
test % 
[1]  + done       python test1.py
```

You can apply those commands to different quantities of scripts too, like:

```
% python test1.py && python test2.py && python test3.py
% python test1.py || python test2.py && python test3.py
```

Comment: Can you open a new terminal first? Then run python on it and then click on Run selection?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can open as many terminals as you need clicking on that plus sign on the right of the screen. Every terminal starts as `bash` and then you just need to type `python` to start the interactive mode. The command `Run Selection in Python terminal` will run on the current terminal opened.

Comment: In my case Run selection in Python terminal opens a new terminal or goes back to the terminal it opened originally, it doesn't use the current terminal.

Comment: That's probably a setting issue. This page might help you with that: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: I can see that the terminal you are running things into is called Python, why don't you try to do this process on the terminal called zsh?

Comment: I will edit my answer specifically for the z-shell case.

Comment: Ok, it is possible to run manually a script calling python, but not possible to run a code selection, correct?

Comment: @FrancoPiccolo as far as I know, yes, that's my guess.